# mutate replace, how to specify as character

Tags: r, dplyr

I have this data in which I want to replace "20-Oct" with "10-20" in column "depth". Depth is a factor here.

[BNPP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YmcVU.jpg)

This is what I tried:

```
BNPP <- BNPP %>%
  mutate(depth = replace(depth, depth == "20-Oct", "10-20"))
```

And I got this error message:

```
Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, list, value = "10-20") :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
```

So I tried to fix it by doing this:

```
BNPP <- BNPP %>%
  BNPP$depth <- as.character(BNPP$depth) %>%
  mutate(depth = replace(depth, depth == "20-Oct", "10-20"))
```

And I got a different error message:

```
 Error in UseMethod("mutate_") : 
      no applicable method for 'mutate_' applied to an object of class "character"
```

I tried putting the as.character outside the code chunk and it worked, but I have no idea why:

```
BNPP$depth <- as.character(BNPP$depth)
BNPP <- BNPP %>%
  mutate(depth = replace(depth, depth == "20-Oct", "10-20"))
```

I would appreciate an explanation for why the first one doesn't work but the last one works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test this. Stole the sample df from TC Zhang but changed the name to suit the question.

```
library(hablar)
library(dplyr)

BNPP <- data.frame(
  plot = c(1,1,1),
  subplot = c("B","B", "B"),
  depth = c("0-10","20-Oct", "20-30")
)

BNPP %>% 
  convert(chr(depth)) %>% 
  mutate(depth = if_else(depth == "20-Oct", "10-20", depth))
```

gives

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
   plot subplot depth
  <dbl> <fct>   <chr>
1     1 B       0-10 
2     1 B       10-20
3     1 B       20-30
```

Comment: Thanks, @davsjob! So is it the replace function that was giving me the error message or the as.character function?

Comment: @Bean It was the <- in the second row. WIth %>% you dont need to assign the function to the data frame more than once. :) df %>% fun1 %>% fun2 works fine.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you!! @davsjob

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an excel auto-correct issue( which is hilarious by the way).

The error message tells you that "10-20" is not in the `levels(BNPP$depth)`, so you can't directly mutate "20-Oct" to something else.

An easy fix is to convert BNPP$depth as a Character vector, then mutate it:
(During the test I find that mutate+gsub will do the conversion for you)

```r
library(dplyr)

# data
df <- data.frame(
  plot = c(1,1,1),
  subplot = c("B","B", "B"),
  depth = c("0-10","20-Oct", "20-30")
)

# mutate depth

df.new <-
  df %>%
  mutate(depth = gsub("20-Oct","10-20", depth))

df.new
#>   plot subplot depth
#> 1    1       B  0-10
#> 2    1       B 10-20
#> 3    1       B 20-30
```

<sup>Created on 2018-11-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>